# ASP.NET Datasource displaying all data on different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm working on a webproject, I have made a SQL-datasource in ASP.NET that gets data from my Database. The Insert works and looks like this.

```
    //Data put in textboxes gets inserted into DB
      SqlConnection con6 = new       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jaklin11ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con6.Open();
        string cmd = "INSERT INTO [Workout] (Date, Time, Distance, Email, Activity) VALUES   (@Date, @Time, @Distance, @Email, @Activity)";
        SqlCommand insertWorkout = new SqlCommand(cmd, con6);

        insertWorkout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", textDateWorkout.Text);
        insertWorkout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", textTimeWorkout.Text);
        insertWorkout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distance", textDistanceWorkout.Text);
        insertWorkout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", ddlrunningwalking.Text);
        insertWorkout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textEmailWorkout.Text);

        try
        {
            insertWorkout.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con6.Close();
            Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/Workout.aspx"); //Refresh the page after addning workout
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = (ex.Message); //Otherwise error
       } 
    }
}
```

Its working perfectly fine and it places the data in right places when I check my SQL-server.

*However*, my datasource `FORMVIEW` doesnt understand the session, and Displays User1 stats when User2 is logged in. I can't figure out why.

```
**Code for the gridview**
SELECT * FROM   [Workout] WHERE ([Email] = @Email) ORDER BY [Date] DESC,
```

Comment: Why it should? You are not filering the query at all..

Comment: Where in the [Workout] table do you distinguish between the 2 users?

Comment: I choose it in a earlier code, that distinguishes the session for the logged in user, BUT the formview doesnt separate them

Comment: @granadaCoder I imagine the Email column distinguishes the user.
andrejcurcic - Could you show us the formview?  That's the code we need to see to give you an answer.

Comment: How does `@Email` get provided to the data source?